# How many Docker service replicas do I need?

Tags: docker

What is the scale of a docker service replica? Is it 1:1 where I need a replica for each user on the site, or is it on request? I am putting together a small site that won't see a ton of traffic. How many replicas do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to guess the best number of replicas needed if you don't have any quantitative measure to assess performance and the load on your service.

Creating a replica per user or per request is too much, unless you are doing some extreme computation per request that will need a huge amount of time and resources to complete.

My advice is start with only one replica and monitor the load on your service and adjust accordingly. If you don't have much load and your site is lightweight you won't need to replicate your service, one will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you might consider having more than one replica.

In case of failure of one instance for whatever reason, Docker will restart that instance and your system will not experience downtime while there will be other instances (replicas) running alongside.

I am running a system with some replicas so that even with few users requests are distributed among them.